# Ansible 2.8.6 iterate over list nested in dictionary

Tags: python, ansible

With ansible 2.8.6 I run  a shell command and i want to get the stdout_lines.

For example:

```
- name: Find the output
  shell: ls -1 /example
  register: examples
  changed_when: False
```

`examples` is a dictionary and later on I want to use the `examples.stdout_lines` which is a list.

```
- name: iterate the output
  shell: "echo '- - -' > /example/{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ examples.stdout_lines  }}"
  changed_when: False
```

But it returns an error:

```
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ansible-2.8.6-py3.6.egg/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 103, in run
    items = self._get_loop_items()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ansible-2.8.6-py3.6.egg/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 232, in _get_loop_items
    convert_bare=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ansible-2.8.6-py3.6.egg/ansible/utils/listify.py", line 33, in listify_lookup_plugin_terms
    terms = templar.template(terms.strip(), convert_bare=convert_bare, fail_on_undefined=fail_on_undefined)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ansible-2.8.6-py3.6.egg/ansible/template/__init__.py", line 548, in template
    eval_results = safe_eval(result, include_exceptions=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ansible-2.8.6-py3.6.egg/ansible/template/safe_eval.py", line 108, in safe_eval
    filter_list.extend(filter_.filters().keys())
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Any ideas on what could be wrong?

**EDIT: this is the debug output**

```
TASK [role: debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

Wednesday 10 February 2021  **** 

ok: [vm0] => {
    "msg": " stdout_lines =  ['host0', 'host1', 'host2'] scsi_hosts = {'changed': False, 'end': '2021-02-10 ', 'stdout': 'host0\\nhost1\\nhost2', 'cmd': 'ls -1 /sys/class/scsi_host/', 'rc': 0, 'start': '2021-02-10', 'stderr': '', 'delta': '0:00:00.003999', 'stdout_lines': ['host0', 'host1', 'host2'], 'stderr_lines': [], 'failed': False}"
}
ok: [vm1] => {
    "msg": " stdout_lines =  ['host0', 'host1', 'host2'] scsi_hosts = {'changed': False, 'end': '2021-02-10', 'stdout': 'host0\\nhost1\\nhost2', 'cmd': 'ls -1 /sys/class/scsi_host/', 'rc': 0, 'start': '2021-02-10 ', 'stderr': '', 'delta': '0:00:00.004027', 'stdout_lines': ['host0', 'host1', 'host2'], 'stderr_lines': [], 'failed': False}"
}
```

The actual output is the python error as described above plus the error report:

```
fatal: [vm0]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.",
    "stdout": ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Ansible code is correct. The error you're describing is a Python error, and not an Ansible error.

Make sure the folder isn't empty.

Can you provide the actual Ansible output? And also the debug msg of 'examples'?

-- edit --

What happens if you:

```yaml
  debug: "{{ item }}"
    msg: "{{ examples.stdout_lines  }}"
```

If that doesn't output any error, it's most likely the shell module failing you somehow. Try executing that code with `become: true`, or without the loop.

Comment: Thanks for answering, however I already tried that and it didn't work. Whenever I debug the stdout_lines it prints out ok. I cannot get it to work inside the loop.

Comment: I edited the description adding the debug output. The error is the same as described plus some finale error report. It doesn't have some extra description. scsi_hosts is the "examples" variable.

Comment: I tried using become: true,but the output was the same. I didn't really get the first line with the debug: "{{ item }}". It seems to be some kind of problem with the template. It used to work with older ansible versions.